# Couchbase lite upgradation to 1.2

Tags: ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite

What is the difference between [CBLManager sharedInstance] and [[CBLManager sharedInstance] copy] ?

Why [CBLManager sharedInstance] is not allowing to close the manager?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing from your question that you are using the iOS version of CBLite.
the copy is a method which copies the instance of the Manager in order to use it in another thread or just to create of copy of it.

by close the manager you mean close the connection? what kind of exception do you get?

Comment: This is correct, but I'll add that you are not allowed to close the shared manager since it doesn't belong to you.